# Yii2: ActiveRecord How to unload / unset a model of all(some) attributes?

Tags: activerecord, yii, yii2

Yii2 ActiveRecord has a method to automatically load a form data into a model using [`load()`](http://www.yiiframework.com/doc-2.0/yii-base-model.html#load%28%29-detail)  which is very good as it safely loads the model with data, However I am not able find a equivalent method to unload the model of all the attributes.

i.e. Is there a method to unset all attributes of a model in Yii2, like the [`unSetAttributes()`](http://www.yiiframework.com/doc/api/1.1/CModel#unsetAttributes-detail) method in Yii 1.x ?

Currently the only way to do this seems to be either

```
$model->setAttributes(['attribute1'=>NULL,'attribute2' => NULL ... ]);
```

or

```
foreach ($model->attributes as $attribute) {
    $model->$attribute = NULL; 
}
```

<strike>**Edit**: To clarify in response to [Samuel Liew's answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/25132137/1900483), while at this point I only wanted to unset all attributes which I could do by reiniting the model, I would also like to control which attributes are getting reset, which `unSetAttributes` provided</strike>

Comment: Per Issue #4596(https://github.com/yiisoft/yii2/issues/4596) on the source repo, this is not being implemented because AR models no longer loads values by default, if you still need it like me, Samuel Liew's answer is a way to do it.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You could simply create a new instance of the model.

```
$model = new MyModel;
```

Or as you can see, [unsetAttributes in Yii 1](http://www.yiiframework.com/doc/api/1.1/CModel#unsetAttributes-detail) is like this, you could simply implement it in your base model:

```
public function unsetAttributes($names=null)
{
    if($names===null)
        $names=$this->attributeNames();
    foreach($names as $name)
        $this->$name=null;
}
```

Comment: Of course, but i would prefer control over what gets unloaded, unSetAttributes gives this control, you can specify which attributes to unset if you wish. Was there any reason this is no longer supported ?

Comment: thats what i ended up doing by extending ActiveRecord

Comment: if you do new MyModel then the model gets populated with the default attributes I guess, which would not be the same as completly resetting them.